# Git merge without staging changes

Tags: git

I'd like to merge in a branch without staging the automatically merged files for commit.  I anticipate the merge being messy, and I'd like to use `git diff` to review all of the changes before committing.  The `--no-commit` flag prevents the commit from being completed, but the files are still staged.  Is there a way to merge without staging the files for commit?

Comment: Why does it matter if they are staged or not? They will still show up in `git diff`. You could do a `git reset` to unstage them

Comment: I've never seen staged files show up in a diff.

Comment: Huh, fair enough. `git diff HEAD` will show staged and unstaged chages. `git reset` will unstage all changes

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon - git reset seems to also clear the "merge in progress" flag.

I am actually looking for something similar... I want to start a merge (i.e. be prepared for 2 parents, yet have NO actual changes in the working tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

The technical reason for this is that Git's merging actually happens *in the index*, which gets temporarily expanded, to hold all three input commits.  As each file is successfully merged (without conflicts), Git shrinks that particular index entry right back down to a single slot-zero entry—which is therefore staged for commit.  For conflicting files, Git leaves that index entry as three occupied slots numbered 1 (merge base), 2 (`--ours` or HEAD commit version), and 3 (`--theirs`).

During merging, the work-tree files are mostly just dummies / scratch-pads, except for the fact that Git updates them to hold its attempt at merging.  All the real action is in the index.  If all goes well, all the work-tree files get updated to match the final slot-zero copy, i.e., it looks like Git has staged them.  But it actually went the other way: the right version went into the index at slot zero, and then Git did a `git checkout-index` style operation to copy the index file into the work-tree.

As [EncryptedWatermelon said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58960567/git-merge-without-staging-changes#comment104176513_58960567), you can use `git reset` here:

```
git reset HEAD -- <filename>
```

tells Git to copy the `HEAD` commit's entry for the file to the index's entry for that file.  Using `git reset --mixed HEAD`, which can be spelled `git reset` with no options, tells Git to do that for *every* file.<sup>1</sup>  There's no direct / immediate value to using `git reset` like this, because you can use `git diff --cached` to compare `HEAD` vs index, if you want to look at what's going on with the updated index copies of files.  But you *can* do it if you like, and if you want to un-stage everything and then stage only a few things, for whatever reason, it's available.

---

<sup>1</sup>This `--mixed` form of `git reset` also directs Git to update the current branch name so that its stored hash ID is its current stored hash ID.  If you spelled it `git reset --mixed hash`, you'd reset the index from the specified hash ID and write the specified hash ID into the current branch name.  By using `HEAD`, we force the "change" to the branch name to be "set it to its current value", i.e., don't move it at all.  This leaves the overwrite of the index contents as the only visible effect.

Answer (score 6):

If its just about reviewing, you could see the staged changes using `git diff --cached`. Would that work for you situation?

Comment: If you want a technical answer to the question as you asked it, see torek's answer; but when it comes to addressing your stated problem, this is the simplest, most reasonable solution.

Comment: Fair answer if the merge is small; but in other work places, the policy favors large merges instead; so then I'd like to be able to check off each file (explicitly `git add` them before `git commit` of the merge).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **reset** to move all the files that get staged after `git merge <branch name> --no-commit` back into changes not staged for commit.

`git reset HEAD -- .`